# egg-sequelize server online error:Class constructor LRUCache cannot be invoked without 'new'？

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Now, i am using eggjs to develop a system and the program running in the local environment is okay. but when i set up my program in the server, the problem informed me that：
error:

```
8 ERROR 33 nodejs.SequelizeConnectionError: Class constructor LRUCache cannot be invoked without 'new’
at Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:133:19)
at tryCatcher (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
at _drainQueue (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/src/BDMS/bdmsback/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
name: "SequelizeConnectionError"
parent: {}
original: {}
pid: 33
```

I find a similar solution in the github sequelize/sequelize#7840:https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840.

or another discussrion tell me i should use lower version of Lrucaache version.
https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/issues/147

The advice is modify the .babelrc etc .
Actually, I dont have the file in my project, though i used babel package.
i try to add the file .babelrc and other advice appeared in the below discussion.

but it didnt work at all.

The server can run in the server correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by edit the Dockerfile as `RUN npm i`.
Not the `RUN npm i --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org，`
The problem is caused by the npm package problem provided by taobao.com in China, running in the Docker, use the official npm package is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after modifying the version from `"lru-cache": "^6.0.0"` to `"lru-cache": "^4.1.5"`